# Symfony2 Exception Response. Replace 404 status code with 200

Tags: symfony, exception, response

I have a 404 handler in symfony2 which is an EventListener.

With certain 404's, I do a redirect, which works great. To the browser, no 404 is thrown.

```
new RedirectResponse( $newURL );
```

That line basically replaces the 404 status code with a 200.

In other cases though, I want to return some content instead, not a 404 message, but some replacement data. Something like this:

```
$response = new Response( $returnJSONMessage );
$response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
$response->setStatusCode(200);
```

Code wise, this is fine, but it doesn't stop the 404 being returned. I am guessing because it sits within this:

```
$event->setResponse( $theResponse );
```

Which is of type GetResponseForExceptionEvent.

What do I need to call, to get it to return my data as a 200 instead of a 404. In the same way that RedirectResponse seems to.
I tried:

```
$event->stopPropagation();
```

But it is a bit after the fact. It seems anything within $event->setResponse which isn't a RedirectResponse gets labelled a 404 in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally found what I was looking for via a Symfony GitHub pull;

```
$response->headers->set( 'X-Status-Code', 200 );
```

Allows you to override the exception status code.

```
$response->setStatusCode(200);
```

Will not work.

Request here:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/5043

Pull here:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/118a5d2274dc7d6701c3e2a758b820cd49ebaf3b

Answer (score 4):

The suggestions provided here didn't work for me.

And then I found out why - **X-Status-Code is deprecated since Symfony 3.3**.

What worked for me was using *$event->allowCustomResponseCode();*

```
$exception = $event->getException();
$response = new Response('...', 404);

// ...

$event->allowCustomResponseCode();
$event->setResponse($response);
```

Here is a link about this on [Symfony website](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-deprecated-x-status-code)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue following code.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
...
$event->setException(new HttpException(200));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after trying multiple solutions, I used the [Event Subscriber from Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) and declared the event Kernel Response :

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE][] = ['onKernelResponse', 0];
    return $events;
  }
```

And then, in the function onKernelResponse, I put my code to return 200 instead of 404 in specific cases :

```
  /**
   * @param FilterResponseEvent $event
   */
  public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    // Custom code to check which URL needs to return 200.
    $check_url_200 = $this->myOwnService->checkURL();
    if ($check_url_200) {
      $response = $event->getResponse();
      $status_code = $response->getStatusCode() == Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND ? Response::HTTP_OK : $response->getStatusCode();
      $response->setStatusCode($status_code);
      $event->setResponse($response);
    }
  }
```