# Symfony 5.4 with Api-Platform - mask response status code and add additional property in the JSON

Tags: php, rest, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony5

I have a REST API with Symfony 5.4 and Api-Platform 2.7. I have to do the following:
Whenever there is any error (response status code >2xx) I have to return code 200 and the real code must be included in a new property "code" in the response JSON.

I have tried the following but to no avail: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using this thread: [Symfony2 Exception Response. Replace 404 status code with 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387354/symfony2-exception-response-replace-404-status-code-with-200)

My problem was that initially I used KernelEvents::VIEW, and I didn't have access to the Response object. I switched to KernelEvents::RESPONSE and now I have.
My final solution is this:

```
<?php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use ApiPlatform\Symfony\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent;

final class StatusCodeSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => ['changeStatusCode', EventPriorities::POST_RESPOND],
        ];
    }

    public function changeStatusCode(ResponseEvent $event): void
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $content = json_decode($response->getContent());

        if ($statusCode >= 300) {
            $response->setStatusCode(200);
            $content->code = $statusCode;
            $response->setContent(json_encode($content));
        } 
    }
}
```